# I had made an form in html and need to add serial number which increases on submitting the form as shown in the code in invoice column

Tags: html, forms

I had made an form in html and need to add serial number which increases on submitting the form as shown in the code in invoice column.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Invoice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="license" href="http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license/">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    <h1>Invoice</h1>
    <address contenteditable>
      <p>Jonathan Neal</p>
      <p>101 E. Chapman Ave<br>Orange, CA 92866</p>
      <p>(800) 555-1234</p>
   </address>
   <span>
     <img alt="" src="logo.png">
     <input type="file" accept="image/*">
   </span>
 </header>
 <article>
   <h1>Recipient</h1>
   <address contenteditable>
     <p>Some Company<br>c/o Some Guy</p>
   </address>
   <table class="meta">
  ***<tr>enter code here
     <th><span contenteditable>Invoice #</span></th>
     <td><span contenteditable>101138</span></td>
     </tr>***
     <tr>
     <th><span contenteditable>Date</span></th>
     <td><span contenteditable>January 1, 2012</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <th><span contenteditable>Amount Due</span></th>
     <td><span id="prefix" contenteditable>$</span>
     <span>600.00</span>
     </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Should it increase for every user? Or just for this user? You might need a server to do that...

Comment: only for this user

Comment: can you please give some brief description about putting jscript because i am beggnier and dont know much about jscript

Comment: Luan Nico thank you for answer but can you please give me full answer with js put in html

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: how to make it persistent

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you can use Javascript; first, add an `id` to the element, so you can access it:

```
 <tr>
   <th><span contenteditable>Invoice #</span></th>
   <td><span contenteditable id="invoce">101138</span></td>
 </tr>
```

Then, you can add the following js to your script file:

```
var invoice = 101138;
$('button').on('click', function () {
    invoice++; // increments invoice
    $('#invoice').text(invoice); // updates text on screen
});
```

That is, if you are using jquery, and `'button'` is the selector for your button.

That, however, will reset when the user leaves the site. If you want it to be persistent, you need to use something like cookies or localstorage.

In order to make it persistent, you can use a plethora of ways, e.g., the [local storage api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0kgn5x6a/1/)'s a complete example.